Qiskit RealAmplitudes changes bits ordering
I use qiskit 1.1.2.
The RealAmplitudes circuit should be the identity operator if all the parameters are set to zero. Is that right?
Even for 3-qbit system, the Statevectors seem to change when evolved by this circuit.
For example taking Statevector as a pure state corresponding to some binary string, I obtain a different pure state.
The simplest example of this behaviour can be reconstructed using the following instructions:
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes

noQBits = 3
linear_dim = 2**noQBits

ansatz = RealAmplitudes(noQBits, reps=1, entanglement='full', insert_barriers=True)

psiTime0 = [0]*(linear_dim)
psiTime0[2] = 1
psiTime0 = Statevector(psiTime0,)

aer_sim = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=aer_sim, optimization_level=1)

gateEvolver = ansatz.assign_parameters(np.zeros(ansatz.num_parameters))
psiTest0 = psiTime0.evolve(gateEvolver)

prob0 = psiTime0.probabilities_dict()
probTest0 = psiTest0.probabilities_dict()

print(prob0)
print(probTest0)

Why the states (present in probability distribution) are labeled differently? How can I fix it?

RealAmplitudes is composed using a two-local circuit, which "consists of alternating layers of $Y$ rotations and $CX$ entanglements." So even with all rotations being $0$, the circuit is not the identity.
This is how the circuit looks like for the code you have, so of course the $CX$ gates will change the state at the output:

